# VISA read Com port

Tags: visa

everyone! I have a device which is connected to usb by fibre optic line through the adapter called "usb-rs232 converter". OS windows see that device like COM3-port. NI-VISA find that device like ASRL3::INSTR but I can't read data. I got an error VI_ERROR_TMO. How do I fix it ? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to communicate with the device using NI-MAX or your own code?

Comment: Hey!  Thanks for the reply. I sorted it out. Sent some commands to the device and got reply. Yeah! Gonna make a pyvisa program to handle my devices.

Comment: Yeah, pyvisa works great for me.